# Python serial commands to send CTRL+ L

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, pyserial

I have a customer display, that's connected to serial port. I am using a windows machine for this.

[image]

**I want to send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to clear the display of customer display, but I cannot find a solution that helps me. Basically I wish to send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+'any commands' in future.**

In command Prompt I can use "<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> " to clear the existing display and display the text. The following is the command that gets displayed in prompt

```
echo ^LDisplay me > COMX // ^L is actually CTRL + L
```

The above will output as ,

1. Clears the display.
2. Displays "Display me"

Now I am trying to achieve the same thing using Python serial connector.

```
import serial
ser = Serial ('COM5',timeout=2)
ser.write("\x0C") # equivalent to ctrl+L
```

This does not work at all. I get error as `

> Exception in serial connection:  unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes:'\x03'

However if I try the following for normal texts, it works perfectly,

```
ser.write("Display me".encode()
```

This displays "Display me" in the customer display.

I tried to use `ser.write("\x0C".encode())` but I get no output.

I get error as

> Exception in serial connection: unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes:'\x1fc\x00'

I would appreciate any suggestions, improvements and help to solve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To encode a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> as bytes in Python3, you should use:

```
b'\x0c'
```

#### Why?

Ascii control characters are encoded as their position in the alphabet, so <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, since it is the third letter of the alphabet, encoded as a hex string, would be `\x03`. Similarly, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> would `\x0c` (hex C is decimal 12).

In python 3 to get bytes, you can pre-pend the string with a `b`.